# How do I alter the page title after a controller sets the title?

Tags: 8

Is it possible to modify a page title after a controller sets `#title` in the main element?

Normally you can modify the page title by setting `_title` or `_title_callback` in the route. However it seems that you cannot alter the page title if a controller sets `#title`.

(A correct answer would affect both the HTML `<title>` and the system title block.)

Comment: Specifically, my problem is Page Manager sets a title, and it seems I cannot modify page title with custom code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `#title` from the controller overrides the title set in the route. There doesn't seem to be another override to override `#title`.

Though you could try to alter the controller output in a [KernelEvents::VIEW](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-kernel%21KernelEvents.php/constant/KernelEvents%3A%3AVIEW/8.3.x) with a priority higher than 0 like this:

```
$result = $event->getControllerResult();
// change the controller output
$event->setControllerResult($result);
```

---

**Metatag**

Working on a project I found out, that the metatag module in default configuration gets the title with the token `[current-page:title]`, which retrieves the title from the route, ignoring `#title` set in the controller. Most times this would be considered as an unwanted side effect, but in your case you get the title you want from the route title callback in HTML `<title>` and only have to take care of the page title block, which should be no problem in a preprocess hook.