# How can I set a custom document title in theme-settings.php?

Tags: 8, theming

I need to set the content of the `<title>` tag without using a module, for example changing the content of the *theme-settings.php* file.

I am trying to add the following hook implementation.

```php
function mythemename_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = 'New title';
}
```

The new title is not shown, though.

If it makes any difference, I am using Drupal 8.7.3.

Comment: This is a rather complex issue, but most times you should be able to get the result you want by using the module Metatag. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238704/how-do-i-alter-the-page-title-after-a-controller-sets-the-title

Comment: You need to use the THEMENAME.theme file to store this in.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use the Metatag module, indeed.

For a full code solution, I'd recommend you to have a look at core/themes/classy/templates/layout/html.html.twig file (which is the default html template used by Drupal if your theme does not override it) for clues concerning template variables.
The variable you want to alter is head_title which, as stated in header of html.html.twig is:

```
 * - head_title: List of text elements that make up the head_title variable.
 *   May contain one or more of the following:
 *   - title: The title of the page.
 *   - name: The name of the site.
 *   - slogan: The slogan of the site.
```

In your theme myTheme.theme file, use the hook_preprocess_html() hook to alter your $variables["head_title"] variable.

PS: Do not forget to flush caches when working with templates to be sure your modifications are taken into account.